# Outlook errors and blank address book?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a user with a fresh install of Windows 7 64 bit.  Office 2010 was installed also.  Everything worked great until we installed Adobe Pro 9 and Wordperfect 12.  (for outlook we are not using exchange).

Then Outlook popped an error saying could not start Outlook.  I then modified it to run in compatibility mode and Outlook starts.  Then took compatibility mode off and outlook continues to start without difficulty.

However, her address book went blank (contacts are all there).  In the properties of the contact folder it is checked (and grayed out) to include this folder in the address book, and the Outlook address book is listed when I look at account properties.

I tried creating a new profile to no avail.  I tried creating a new profile and creating a new pst file - to no avail.  I tried uninstalling office, removing the folders inside roaming and local, reinstalled office; got the same could not start Outlook error - did the compatibility mode bit and got it to start - but the Address book continues to be empty.

Has anyone run across this before?  I'm thinking that there must be some other preferences type folder other than those in Roaming and Local since her signature remained when I reinstalled Office.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Windows 7 64 bit. Office 2010 (not sure if the root cause is the same). Similarly, I tried multiple combinations of creating new Mail Profiles and .PSTs without success. I also re-installed Outlook 2010 separately and then all of Office 2010 and the problem was not resolved.

Eventually with the help of Microsoft support, I un-installed Outlook 2010 and then deleted four Registry Key folders (via regedit) before re-installing Outlook 2010. This resolved the problem and my contacts folder was again visible in the E-Mail Address Book.

Both under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, the following folders (and contents) must be deleted after un-installing Outlook 2010

```
Software\Microsoft\office\outlook

Software\Microsoft\office\14.0\outlook
```

Un-installing Outlook 2010 does not automatically remove these registry keys, and they somehow effected the Address book.